# What is the Turing degree of Truth?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, computability, foundations

First of all by Truth I mean the set $T$ of the Gôdel numbers of  the true formulas of first order arithmetic.

First order arithmetic is not decidable and $T$ is not decidable, additionally
the undefinability theorem says that $T$ can not be expressed in first order logic, so $T$ does not belong to the arithmetical hierarchy and his Turing degree is at least $\omega$.

What is then the Turing degree of $T$?

Is there a good textbook that somebody can suggest where this kind of subjects are explained thoroughly?

Comment: See [Turing degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree#References) for bibliography.

Comment: Indeed its degree is $0^{(\omega)}$, the Turing join of the $0^{(n)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $T$ does not belong to the arithmetical hierarchy and his Turing degree is at least $\omega$.

A couple quick comments:

- I assume "$\omega$" should be "$0^{(\omega)}$" - in which case that's correct - since $\omega$ isn't a Turing degree.
- More substantively, there's a serious issue in your reasoning. You're right that $T$ can't be arithmetic. However, that is  *not* sufficient to conclude that $T\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$: there are Turing degrees incomparable with $0^{(\omega)}$ (and hence not arithmetic *or* $\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$), and even Turing degrees *above every arithmetic set* which are incomparable with $0^{(\omega)}$ (this second fact is an instance of the more general **exact pair theorem**).

To show that $T\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$, you need to argue that given $\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathbb{N}^2$ you can find - computably - a sentence $\varphi$ which is true iff $b\in 0^{(a)}$. You can do that via Kleene's $T$-predicate. Conversely, to show $0^{(\omega)}\ge_TT$ you just show that uniformly the $\Sigma_n$-theory of $\mathbb{N}$ has Turing degree $0^{(n)}$. Soare's book is a good source on this material.